# Fast way to merge two maps?

Tags: c++

I have 2 maps:

`map<int,BigObject> a,b;`

If `a` and `b` do not share any keys is there a way to merge `b` into `a`,  which does not copy the `BigObject` objects?

Copying the `BigObject` objects is a bottle neck.

Comment: In C++17 you can do [merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) but thats not quite out yet I think. Otherwise you might be able to std::move elements individually if that happens to be faster.

Comment: No, there isn't. You should store `std::shared_ptr`s to your BigObjects, instead. Then, this becomes a no-brainer.

Comment: I'd suggest unique_ptr and moving instead of shared_ptr, since that is closer to the original semantics, if BigObject can't itself be moved.

Comment: Are `BigObject` movable?

Comment: What is `BigObject` ? Whether you would get any benefit from `move` would depend on that. Another option is to make use of any smart pointer as you like.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you should do is make `BigObject` cheap to move, and maybe make it no-copy.  One way to do this is to move their big, expensive state into a `std::unique_ptr< InternalState >`.  If you still *need* copy (I find you often do not), you'll probably want a `value_ptr< InternalState >`, either getting the value ptr from a library like `boost` or writing your own.

Failing that, you can wait for C++17.  In C++17, (some?) associative node-based containers gain the ability to quickly move sets of nodes between them.  This includes `std::map`.

Failing that, your map can be from a key to a `unique_ptr<BigObject>`.  This adds a small amount of indirection to other uses of your map, but they are now cheaply movable.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments point out, if copying the `BigObject` is expensive, then you should deal with pointers or references in the first place...

But if you happen to merge only very few maps, then you could just write a wrapper that checks the few merged maps sequentially when reading (and writing...).